# DB2 JNDI is not working with Servlet 2.5 in WebSphere 7.0

Tags: java, servlets, db2, jndi, websphere-7

I am having an error when I want to use DB2 via JNDI. I looked for this in other posts but there are not the same error as mine in any.

First of all, I created a pool connection DB2 in WebSphere 7.0 using the driver: `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource` and JNDI `asisa/conector/db2`.

Next step I followed was in the `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description></description>
    <res-ref-name>indirectDB2</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    <mapped-name>indirectDB2</mapped-name>     
</resource-ref>
```

And the last step was in the `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd 
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <resource-ref name="indirectDB2" binding-name="asisa/conector/db2" />

</web-bnd>
```

In my web application I am trying to connect with Java like this:

```
Context aContext = new InitialContext();
DataSource aDataSource =(DataSource)aContext.lookup("java:comp/env/indirectDB2");
Connection conn = aDataSource.getConnection();
```

I think there are no more to do but I still receiving the same error and it is related to the servlet I'm using:

> com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is com.ibm.websphere.naming.CannotInstantiateObjectException: Exception occurred while the JNDI NamingManager was processing a javax.naming.Reference object. [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Attempted to use a 4.0 DataSource from a 2.3 (or higher) servlet. Invalid configuration.]]

I tried a lot of ways to resolved it but I can't down the servlet version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change your web.xml to indicate the proper type class of 
javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource.  Posting the resources.xml from the scope at which the datasource was created will help in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the error message it says:

```
Attempted to use a 4.0 DataSource from a 2.3 (or higher) servlet. Invalid configuration.
```

Are you sure you configured your data source in the `Resources > Data sources` and NOT in the `Data sources (WebSphere Application Server V4)`?

Double check, if it is not defined as V4.

Comment: It is correct that it is configured in Data Sources. The connection test is ok too.

Comment: @ClaraMG I've done it hundred times and didnt see such a message. So the only reason is that you have data source with same name in V4 section. Are you perhaps bundling driver in the application?

Comment: It was happening two different things; the first one: WAS was getting the db2jcc4.jar by default and the second one was that after making several tests I had two pool in my application (one via EAR and the other one in the server). Thank you very much and sorry for bothering you.